# Reassigning index in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate, but suppose I have a pandas DataFrame and I've sorted the rows based on the values of some column.  Originally the indices were the integers `0, 1, …, n-1` but now they're out of order.  How do I reassign these indices to be in the proper order for the new sorted DataFrame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`